# How to change the last value in each group by reference, in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

For a data.table DT grouped by site, sorted by time t, I need to change the last value of a variable in each group. I assume it should be possible to do this by reference using :=, but I haven't found a way that works yet.

Sample data:

```
require(data.table)   # using 1.8.11 
DT <- data.table(site=c(rep("A",5), rep("B",4)),t=c(1:5,1:4),a=as.double(c(11:15,21:24)))
setkey(DT, site, t)
DT
#    site t  a
# 1:    A 1 11
# 2:    A 2 12
# 3:    A 3 13
# 4:    A 4 14
# 5:    A 5 15
# 6:    B 1 21
# 7:    B 2 22
# 8:    B 3 23
# 9:    B 4 24
```

The desired result is to change the last value of a in each group, for example to 999, so the result looks like:

```
#    site t   a
# 1:    A 1  11
# 2:    A 2  12
# 3:    A 3  13
# 4:    A 4  14
# 5:    A 5 999
# 6:    B 1  21
# 7:    B 2  22
# 8:    B 3  23
# 9:    B 4 999
```

It seems like .I and/or .N should be used, but I haven't found a form that works. The use of := in the same statement as .I[.N] gives an error. The following gives me the row numbers where the assignment is to be made:

```
DT[, .I[.N], by=site]
#    site V1
# 1:    A  5
# 2:    B  9
```

but I don't seem to be able to use this with a := assignment. The following give errors:

```
DT[.N, a:=999, by=site]
# Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)

DT[, .I[.N, a:=999], by=site]
# Error in `:=`(a, 999) : 
#   := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways.
#  See help(":="). Check is.data.table(DT) is TRUE.

DT[.I[.N], a:=999, by=site]
# Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
```

Is there a way to do this by reference in data.table? Or is this better done another way in R?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Currently you can use:

```
DT[DT[, .I[.N], by = site][['V1']], a := 999]
# or, avoiding the overhead of a second call to `[.data.table`
set(DT, i = DT[,.I[.N],by='site'][['V1']], j = 'a', value = 999L)
```

alternative approaches:

use `replace`...

```
DT[, a := replace(a, .N, 999), by = site]
```

or shift the replacement to the RHS, wrapped by `{}` and return the full vector

```
DT[, a := {a[.N] <- 999L; a}, by = site]
```

or use `mult='last'` and take advantage of `by-without-by`. This requires the data.table to be keyed by the groups of interest.

```
 DT[unique(site), a := 999, mult = 'last']
```

There is a feature request [#2793](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2793&group_id=240&atid=978) that would allow

```
DT[, a[.N] := 999]
```

but this is yet to be implemented

Comment: Thanks @mnel for 4 solutions. +1 for [FR #2793](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2793&group_id=240&atid=978), that will clearly be an elegant way to code this, when implemented.

Comment: @DouglasClark - 5th solution posted. FR#2793 would be the nicest!

Comment: Wow. I haven't seen the "{}" RHS syntax before. Presumably one could execute a whole bunch of operations within the {}, in the context of the group, as long as the last matches length and type of LHS. For example, sort the column and then set both the first and last elements in each group: DT[, a:={a<-sort(a, decreasing=T); a[1]<-888; a[.N]<-999; a}, by=site]. If 'a' within {} can be indexed/subsetted, this seems to already permit much of what FR#2793 would accomplish.

Comment: @DouglasClark --> yes you can do "anything" within `{}`. The scoping on the LHS of `:=` is different, the FR is about allowing the ease of syntax `A[.N] := b` .